# Immediately scale up Kubernetes Statefulset/Deployment to full capacity

Tags: kubernetes, scale, kubernetes-statefulset, statefulset

currently we scaled one of our statefulsets to have 11 replicas. Our current updateStrategy is

```
updateStrategy:
  type: RollingUpdate
```

If we deploy the statefulset from scratch, Kubernetes starts them one after another. To start one replica it needs around 5 Minutes. So in total we wait 55 Minutes just to fill up the capacity.

Is there a way to fill up the capacity at once when starting from scratch? So that all 11 replicas will start simultaneously?

Upgrades on the already existing statefulset should be handled via RollingUpdate due to failure safety.

Best wishes,
Stephan

Answer (score 6, accepted):

we found the answer hiding deep in the documentation:

https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/stateful-application/basic-stateful-set/#parallel-pod-management

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/#pod-management-policies

> **Pod Management Policies**
>
> In Kubernetes 1.7 and later, StatefulSet allows you to relax its ordering guarantees while preserving its uniqueness and identity guarantees via its .spec.podManagementPolicy field.
>
> **OrderedReady Pod Management**
>
> OrderedReady pod management is the default for StatefulSets. It implements the behavior described above.
>
> **Parallel Pod Management**
>
> Parallel pod management tells the StatefulSet controller to launch or terminate all Pods in parallel, and to not wait for Pods to become Running and Ready or completely terminated prior to launching or terminating another Pod. This option only affects the behavior for scaling operations. Updates are not affected.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think so. StatefulSets are designed for safety above all else so the controller operates one pod at a time.